# "keys is not defined" in AngularJS's custom filter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was going through examples in one of Angular JS books that I have and ran into something I do not clearly understand. It has to do with custom filter and ng-repeat. Here are the codes

```
<a ng-click="selectCategory()" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
    Home
</a>
<a ng-repeat="item in data.products | orderBy: 'category' | unique: 'category'" ng-click="selectCategory(item)" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
    {{item}}
</a>
```

The following code is the controller attached to html body tag.

```
angular.module("sportsStore").controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.data = {
    products: [
        {
            name: "Product #1",
            description: "A product",
            category: "Category #1",
            price: 100
        },
        {
            name: "Product #2",
            description: "A product",
            category: "Category #1",
            price: 100
        },
        {
            name: "Product #3",
            description: "A product",
            category: "Category #2",
            price: 210
        },
        {
            name: "Product #4",
            description: "A product",
            category: "Category #3",
            price: 202
        }
    ]
};
```

});

The code for the custom filter is

```
angular.module("customFilters", []).filter("unique", function () {
    return function (data, propertyName) {
        if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
            var results = [];
            var keys = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var val = data[i][propertyName];
                if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                    keys[val] = true;
                    results.push(val);
                }
            }
            return results;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

What the custom filter is supposed to do is basically create a list of categories in $scope.data.products.

The code is working fine. What I do not understand is the role played by "var keys = {};" in the custom filter functions.

What is the intention for having variable "keys" and setting its properties' value to true?

Comment: have you tried running it without `keys[val] = true` to see what difference it makes? I can't see the title of your question reflected in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is executing on the data provided by $scope.data and the property "category".  It checks for unique categories, only showing the first instance of a category.

As the loop executes, it is reading the value for the "category" key on each index of data.

The keys object acts as a tracker to track what values have been added to the results array.

By setting a value on the keys object, it makes it so if that value is encountered again, it will not satisfy the if condition and not add it to the results array.

In other words it executes on Product #1, reads the category as Category #1, adds it to the results array and creates a key["Category #1"] value of true.
Next, Product #2, it extracts the category value of "Category #1".  Category #1 is already on the key object, so it will not add Product #2 to the result.
Next, Product #3, it extracts the category value of "Category #2", sees that it is not in the keys object, so it adds the "Category #2" to the results.

The resulting display should be the Product #1, #3, and #4 info if I am not mistaken.

By removing the keys[val] = true, it will cause all of the products to appear.